# This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'

Tags: ocaml

I'm implementing the Raft protocol and my code is as follows:

```
        let rec request_vote_loop: int = 
          match myState.myRole with
          | Follower -> 0
          | Leader -> 1
          | Candidate -> 
            let trigger = Domain.spawn(fun _ -> Chan.send c TriggerEvent) in
            let request_vote_daemon = Domain.spawn(fun _ -> 
              let rec loop n = 
                if n = 0 then 0
                else let msg = Chan.recv votes in
                match msg with
                | (status, id) -> 
                  Domain.join (Array.get !arr id);
                  if status = 1 then (Array.get votePeers id) := true; (Chan.send c ReceiveVoteEvent); loop (n - 1)
              in loop ((Array.length (!peers)) / 2 + 1 - !current_vote)) in
            let evt = Chan.recv c in
            match evt with
              | TimeoutEvent -> myState.myRole <- Follower; 3
              | AppendEntriesEvent(_) -> 
                myState.myRole <- Follower; 4
              | ReceiveVoteEvent -> 
                if !current_vote > (Array.length (!peers) / 2) then 
                  begin current_vote := !current_vote + 1; myState.myRole <- Leader; 3 end
                else current_vote := !current_vote + 1; request_vote_loop
              | TriggerEvent -> 
                  arr := Array.make (Array.length (!peers)) (Domain.spawn (fun i -> 
                    if (!(Array.get votePeers i)) then 0
                    else
                      let conn = Array.get !peers i in
                      Lwt_main.run 
                        (let+ resp = call_server conn 
                          (RequestVoteArg({
                              candidateNumber = myState.myPersistentState.id;
                              term = myState.myPersistentState.currentTerm;
                              lastlogIndex = (Array.get myState.myPersistentState.logs ((Array.length myState.myPersistentState.logs) - 1)).index;
                              lastlogTerm = (Array.get myState.myPersistentState.logs ((Array.length myState.myPersistentState.logs) - 1)).term
                          })) in (match resp with
                      | Error(s) -> Chan.send votes (0, i); Printf.printf "requestVote: connection failed: %s" s; 1
                      | Ok(repl, s) -> 
                        (match repl with
                        | RequestVoteRet(repl) ->
                          if repl.voteGranted then begin Chan.send votes (1, i); Printf.printf "requestVote: status: %s, currentVote: %d" s !current_vote; 2 end
                          else
                            if not (repl.term = (-1l)) then begin myState.myPersistentState.currentTerm <- repl.term; Chan.send votes (0, i);
                              Printf.printf "requestVote failed because of term: status: %s, currentVote: %d" s !current_vote; 3 end
                            else Chan.send votes (0, i); Printf.printf "requestVote failed: status: %s" s; 4
                        | _ -> failwith "Should not reach here" ))))); request_vote_loop
              | _ -> failwith "Should not reach here"
        in print_endline (Int.to_string request_vote_loop)
```

But there's an error that "This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'", it said my function is of type unit. I don't know what happened...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that spawning domains in a function is a anti-pattern in OCaml 5: the number of domains in a program should constant and less or equal to the number of cores available in the hardware. In other words, domains are not lightweight threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition starts like this:

```
let rec request_vote_loop: int = ...
```

This doesn't define a function, it defines a simple value of type `int`. The reason is that there are no parameters given.

There's too much code to process (and furthermore it's not self-contained). But I suspect you want to define a function that doesn't take any parameters. The way to do this is to pass `()` (known as unit) as the parameter:

```
let rec request_vote_loop () : int = ...
```

The recursive calls look like this:

```
request_vote_loop ()
```

The final call looks like this:

```
Int.to_string (request_vote_loop ())
```